# How can I use ffmpeg and youtube-dl to download the first frame of every video in a playlist?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download only the first frame of every video in a large playlist on YouTube. Does anybody know how I can use ffmpeg and youtube-dl to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to take the playlist ID of the youtube playlist and download the full playlist of the thumbnails you want to get like this:

> youtube-dl -i PLwJ2VKmefmxpUJEGB1ff6yUZ5Zd7Gegn2

Then you use the following [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nkint/8563954/raw/857a0e1e4589dc0fca17138d3ef17a1bae1d4dfe/gistfile1.txt), which will extract the first frame of the all the videos, (do note that after downloading the full playlist all of the videos are in the same directory):

```
i=1
for avi in *.mp4; do
    name=`echo $avi | cut -f1 -d'.'`
    jpg_ext='.jpg'
    echo "$i": extracting the first frame of the video "$avi" into "$name$jpg_ext"
    ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i $avi -vframes 1 -f image2 "$name$jpg_ext"
    i=$((i+1))
 done
```

Comment: I would like the first frame of the video not the thumbnail?

Comment: Oops, yeah by thumbnail I meant first frame

Comment: You're welcome, please do 'vote as answer' if it works for you